# weakref (WeakKeyDictionary) to frame (FrameType) objects

Tags: python, stack-trace, weak-references

I want to have a dict mapping from active frame (`FrameType`) objects to some data. Active meaning that it is in the current execution stack trace.

However, holding a reference to the frame object is not a good idea because that would also keep inactive frames and that will blow up the memory very soon because of all the references to all the local variables.

The natural solution would be to use a weakref to the frame objects, or more specifically `WeakKeyDictionary`.

However, currently it is not possible to create a weakref to a frame object:

```py
import weakref
import sys

f = sys._getframe()
weakref.ref(f)
```

yields

```
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'frame' object
```

I assume this is a CPython implementation detail?

So, what are the options?

I could maybe anyway create references but try to clean them up as soon as possible when they are not active anymore. [How do I actually check if a frame object is active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72270187/how-to-check-if-frame-object-is-active)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a crazy idea: If you can't hold a reference to the frame, make the frame hold a reference to you.

```
class FrameDict:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data_by_frame_id = {}
    
    def __setitem__(self, frame, data):
        frame_id = id(frame)
        
        # Make the frame hold a reference to a KeyDeleter, so when the frame
        # dies, the KeyDeleter dies, and the frame is removed from the dict
        deleter = KeyDeleter(self._data_by_frame_id, frame_id)
        frame.f_locals[deleter] = deleter

        self._data_by_frame_id[frame_id] = data
    
    def __getitem__(self, frame):
        frame_id = id(frame)
        return self._data_by_frame_id[frame_id]
        

class KeyDeleter:
    def __init__(self, mapping, key):
        self.mapping = mapping
        self.key = key
    
    def __del__(self):
        del self.mapping[self.key]
```

Demo:

```
import inspect

def new_frame():
    return inspect.currentframe()

frame_dict = FrameDict()

frame = new_frame()
frame_dict[frame] = 'foobar'
print(frame_dict[frame])  # foobar

del frame
print(frame_dict._data_by_frame_id)  # {}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. But is it safe to write to `frame.f_locals`? Another problem is that `id` is only unique during the lifetime of objects, so your `__getitem__` could return invalid data.

Comment: @Albert `f_locals` is a documented attribute; it's listed in [this massive table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members). I don't really see a problem with the id-based mapping either, the chain of events that would have to happen to cause a bug would be 1) frame is deleted 2) new frame is created with the id of the previous frame 3) you look up the new frame in your dict 4) `KeyDeleter.__del__` is executed. I don't think there is a python implementation where that can happen.

Comment: Ah, you asked if it's safe to modify `f_locals`. That's actually a good question. I'm not sure, but hey, it works ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This might fail inside a function – at global scope `locals` and `globals` are the same, but at function scope `locals` is a dynamically built representation of two fixed-size arrays.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm using function locals in my demo, it works fine. In CPython at least.

Comment: The chain "1) frame deleted 2) new frame with id of prev frame 3) `__getitem__` 4) `KeyDeleter.__del__`" can happen with any GC-based Python, esp CPython. Maybe not so often. But run this 1M times and you likely will see it.

Comment: @Albert Well, CPython also uses reference counting, and the GC only cleans up objects that have a reference cycle. So you would first have to create a reference cycle containing a stack frame. And then you would somehow have to call `FrameDict.__getitem__` while the GC is in the middle of cleaning up that refcycle. But if you're still worried, you can reduce the chance of an id-collision happening by storing additional ids. For example, instead of using `id(frame)` as the dict key, use `(id(frame), id(frame.f_back), id(frame.f_locals))`.