# How to check if frame object is active

Tags: python, stack-trace

```py
import sys

frame = sys._getframe()
```

How can I check now whether `frame` (of type `FrameType`) is still active (part of the current execution stack trace)?

I could iterate through the current stack trace (again via `sys._getframe()`) but is there maybe a more efficient or direct way?

Comment: I don't follow. `_getframe()` returns the current frame, so how could the frame possibly *not* be active?

Comment: @Aran-Fey its active when the function is called, but can you check that it's still active half an hour later other than calling `sys._getframe()` again?

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't believe there's another way, no.